# writing www wont work when browsing?

Tags: http, url, jsbin

I always thought that navigating to `www.jsbin.com` is like `jsbin.com`

Now - after i try in my browser :

http://jsbin.com/ is working

but http://www.jsbin.com/ is not working.

is there a reason for this ?

Comment: There is no DNS entry for www.jsbin.com? try nslookup www.jsbin.com and then nslookup jsbin.com, compare the results (or use dig if you're not on windows)

Comment: it is in my fav . there was until yesterday.... im sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `www` as a subdomain to host the primary website for a domain (with duplicate content or redirects on the domain itself) is a convention, not an automated feature of DNS.

For `www.example.com` and `example.com` to return the same website requires that the controller of `example.com` makes it so.

Comment: The reason www/not ww, works is by CNAME records in DNS, not some default magic settings :)

Comment: So the DC has stopped making it so ? ( cause it was in my links of FAV - and I use it regulary)

Comment: Can you elaborate where is this setting ? ( just for curiosity)

Comment: I've no idea what "the DC" is. The setting will either be an A record or a CNAME record, how you set it depends on your DNS server software (or the interface provided to it).